# гиперссылка в тексте сообщения чат бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Имеется текст сообщения, который отправляет теле бот в чат.  В этом сообщении у слова в тесте размещается ссылка:

```py
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Свойства нервных клеток: "[возбудимость] (http:// ....)" и проводимость.', parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Когда сообщение в чате, то рядом со словом в виде гиперссылки адрес web-ресурса, если меняю адрес на путь до файла, где находится обьяснение к слову [возбудимость], то при выполнении кода выходит ошибка:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 341-342: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Вопрос: как сделать так чтобы само слово [возбудимость] в тексте была гиперссылкой и адрес или путь не отображался в тексте сообщения?

Answer (score 0):

> Используйте parse_mode="html" для данного случая

```
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
 'Ваш текст <a href="Ваша ссылка">Слово, которое нужно выделить ссылкой</a>',
 parse_mode='html')
```